# How to update wordpress translations via wp-cli

Tags: wordpress, docker, wp-cli

I'm using docker with the **wordpress:cli** image to perform many actions like updating, activating themes and plugins, etc, on the system.

I come up with a brand new updated system that has everything in it I want, except for the translations. Wordpress-admin informs me that there are updates for translations and I can manually click and update but I obviously want to continue with the cli-style.

Is there any command to achieve such?
Following the documentation in https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/language

I cannot find anything.

Can this be done in any way?

Comment: Where are the updates from? Is it from the core or plugins?

Comment: I'm using wp core update, wp plugin update--all, wp theme update --all and wp language core update

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A bit belated, but it seems that the answer depends on which translations are out of date (core, theme or plugin).

The following two commands did the trick for me :

```
wp language plugin --all update
wp language theme --all update
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I also added `wp language core update` as per https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/language/; weirdly enough `plugins` always results in a `Success: Translations are up to date.` message while firing up the server, but then more translations for plugins are ready when I go to admin.
I checked if swapping it around makes any difference, but it didn't `wp language plugin update --all`.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the "active" status of `wp language plugin list --all`, translations may be not really installed. I finally managed it with this for the es_ES sites:

```
wp language plugin install --all es_ES
```

The Admin panel missage dissapears and some unworking translations runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

To determine what is even installed:

```
wp language plugin list --status=installed --all
wp language plugin list buddypress
```

It seems that all plugins need to support the current site language, because when switching the site language from `en_GB` to `en_US`, the update notice suddenly went away - despite everything else failed so far.